# Can't install gensim with Ubuntu16.04 and anaconda

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, anaconda, gensim, python-3.6

I am trying, unsuccefully, to install a python package (gensim).

```
System details:
I am using Python 3.6.0 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit) with Ubuntu16.04LTS.
```

1. First I followed the directions from [here](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/install.html) (including updating before trying to install), I entered

   ```
   easy_install --upgrade gensim
   ```

   and got the following error massage:

   ```
   Searching for gensim
   Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/gensim/
   Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/gensim/: unknown urltype: https -- Some packages may not be found!
   Couldn't find index page for 'gensim' (maybe misspelled?)
   Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
   Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
   Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: unknown url type:https -- Some packages may not be found!
   No local packages or working download links found for gensim 
   error: Could not find suitable distribution for 
   Requirement.parse('gensim')
   ```
2. When I tried to install using anaconda,

   ```
   conda install -c anaconda gensim=1.0.1
   ```

   as described [here](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/gensim), I got

   ```
   Fetching package metadata ...
   CondaHTTPError: HTTP None None for url 
   <https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/linux-64/repodata.json>
   Elapsed: None

   An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
   HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
   SSLError(SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",),)
   ```
3. When I tried to install directly from git

   ```
   pip install https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim.git
   ```

   I got a similar error

   ```
   SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSLpip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: 
   Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.
   ```
4. I tried to work my way around this by using

   ```
   PYTHONUSERBASE=/home/usr/anaconda3 pip3 install --user --upgrade gensim
   ```

   which was able to install the gensim package, but under a newly created folder `/home/usr/anaconda3/python3.5` even though my default python is python3.6

**Conclusion(?)**:

From [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html) I understood that probably my Python was not compiled with SSL support, and if I fix this I may be able to win this long battle. BUT I don't understand how I can fix this D_:

PLUS, I don't understand why it insists on being installed under python3.5 when the [manual](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gensim) says the package is also compatible with python3.6.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install openssl:

`sudo apt install openssl`

And, then if you installed python from source you have to:

```
./configure
make
sudo checkinstall
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I already have openssl, but I can't figure out what is the meaning of `./configure` (I didn't find any file/folder by this name)

Comment: Why you want to compile python by yourself? Why you don't use precompiled ones?